# How come readthedocs isn't showing latest version?

Tags: read-the-docs

In the following project:

https://readthedocs.org/projects/django-guardian/versions/

Version 1.4.1 isn't showing up. Yet version 1.4.1 is tagged in github, and I have made pushes after this change.

https://github.com/django-guardian/django-guardian/releases

How do I get v1.4.1 to show up? I don't see it in the administration version options either.

(v1.4.0 doesn't show up either, however that is because I manually disabled this revision; there was an error that prevented readthedocs building this version due to a missing dependency)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's strange `1.4.1` should be available  by clicking on latest link from [Django-gourdian versions page](https://readthedocs.org/projects/django-guardian/versions/), maybe that's documentation page haven't updated yet from `1.4.0` to `1.4.1`.

Anyway, you could click on [latest link](http://django-guardian.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) from [Django-gourdian versions page](https://readthedocs.org/projects/django-guardian/versions/) to access  documentation for `Version: 1.4.0`, anyway that's quite closer to latest version...

**Update**

After triggering [builds](https://readthedocs.org/projects/django-guardian/builds/) on latest and stable. [`stable`](http://django-guardian.readthedocs.org/en/stable/) and [`latest`](http://django-guardian.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) point to `Version: 1.4.1` of documentation as supposed to.

Comment: Yes, that is the work around. However the latest link is for the latest developmental release, and people want to be able to access the documentation for the latest stable version. Which is actually the same thing at the moment, but people shouldn't have to know that.

Comment: Stable is now building as v1.4.1. However readthedocs still isn't seeing the v1.4.1 version tag, and as a result http://django-guardian.readthedocs.org/en/v1.4.1/ doesn't exist. Am wondering if maybe because I turned off 1.4.0 it automatically assumes I want to turn off 1.4.*?

Comment: Also if I go to an old version - e.g. http://django-guardian.readthedocs.org/en/v1.2.5/ it tells me that 1.3.2 is the latest version.

Comment: Disregard; 1.4.1 was there in admin, but disabled. I am going to assume you fixed it, and mark your answer as accepted. Thanks.